# C# Merge DataTable with counter

Tags: c#, database, datatable, compare, intersection

In my programm I save and load results as xml files.
I load the old results and want to compare them with the new ones, except the levels.
Only the elements from the new results should be saved.
If an element appears in both old and new results, the level should get increased.

The structure of a result differs but basically looks like this:

```
 --------------------------------------
| ID(int)  | ... | Level(int) |
 --------------------------------------

ID    = Unique identifier, always first; 
...   = Some other stuff depending on the sql query;
Level = Counter, incraeses each time the element appears in results, always last
```

### Example:

oldResults:

```
1 ; Item1 ; 1
2 ; Item2 ; 2
4 ; Item4 ; 1
```

newResults:

```
1 ; Item1 ; 1
2 ; Item2 ; 2
7 ; Item7 ; 1
```

The final table should look like this.

```
1 ; Item1 ; 2
2 ; Item2 ; 3
7 ; Item7 ; 1
```

---

### What I've done so far

```
    // Returns the final DataTable 
    private static DataTable UpdateResults(DataTable oldResults,DataTable newResults) {
        // This is where I want to compare the DataTables          
    }
```

---

### Question

How can I get the intersection of two tables(without the level column) as a new DataTable and increase the level?

Comment: Can you show us what you've done so far?

Comment: I thought the level should increase but the final table's level for `Item2 ` is the same as the old

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes, I corrected it, sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have two `DataTables` and you want to merge the old into the new one by increasing a counter/level column? This approach using LINQ's `ToLookup` should work:

```
var oldIdLookup = oldResults.AsEnumerable().ToLookup(r => r.Field<int>("ID"));
DataTable final = newResults.Clone();
foreach (DataRow row in newResults.Rows)
{
    int id = row.Field<int>("ID");
    int level = row.Field<int>("Level");
    int count = oldIdLookup[id].Count(); // change logic if desired
    int newLevel = level + count;        // change logic if desired
    final.Rows.Add(id, row.Field<string>("Name"), newLevel);
}
```

Comment: Almost correct, I have two DataTables and only want to keep the data from the new dataTable, but increase the level if the data is also present in the old dataTable.

Comment: @er4zox: but that's what i'm doing here. This loops only the new dataTable, so you get all of the new rows. The old rows are just used to lookup the id and to get the new level.